# how to show different values in a table based on another cell value

Tags: html, angularjs

In the picture below I would like to only show the buttons that would be appropriate for the status. for example if the status is new or enabled I should not be able to see the install button. Is it possible to achieve this through HTML or angularJS. As of now the table is just a basic HTML table.

[image]

Comment: put ng-if condition in html

Comment: use `ng-if="item.status=='new' || item.status=='enabled'"`

Comment: ng-if does not seem to be available.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<button ng-if="status == 'new' || status == 'enable'">Install</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. with the ng-if i was able to figure this out. but it also works with ng-show.

```
 <td ng-if="item.status === 'deleted' || item.status ===  'delete'">
                        <button class="btn  btn-primary" ng-click="vm.install(item);">{{'Install' | translate}}</button>
                        <button class="btn  btn-danger" ng-click="vm.remove(item);">{{'Remove' | translate}}</button>
                    </td>
 <td ng-if="item.status === 'error'">
                    <button class="btn  btn-primary" ng-click="vm.install(item);">{{'Re-install' | translate}}</button>
                    <button class="btn  btn-danger" ng-click="vm.remove(item);">{{'Disable' | translate}}</button>
                </td>
```

This allows only the buttons in that row to show that are appropriate for that row based on the status.

Thanks